# IBM ODM With Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-odm

I'm new to IBM ODM, just now I'm experiencing the IBM Operational Decision Manager Z trial.

I need an example or trail or any tutorial for Spring boot applications that are integrated with IBM ODM.

I want a road map for the IBM ODM with Spring Boot.

In the Z trial, I created a Java class and then create a single rule

```
if
    the quantity of Sale is at least 5
    and the widget type of Sale is "red"
then
    set discount to 0.1;
```

I deployed it successfully, but I don't know how to check if the rules are working fine in trial environment.

IBM ODM cloud vs IBM ODM on-premise. Which one is best to use?

kindly show some examples and explain them. How to install ODM in a Local machine?